# Unable to send email via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I need help to find what mistake I am doing , because I'm trying to develop a function that send email from a HTML form using php and ajax , the problem I'm facing is whenever I click on submit bouton the page is refreshing , usually as we can see in the javascript script , I'm supposed to receive a message that shows that it was successfully send

Best regards,

PHP File :

```
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))  {
    //Email information
    $admin_email = "basselbizri@gmail.com";
    $name = $_REQUEST['first_name'];
    $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
    $message = $_REQUEST['message'];

    //send email
    if (mail($admin_email, $name, $message, "From:" . $email)) {
        echo 1;
    }
    else {
        echo 0;
    }
}
?>
```

HTML Form :

```
<form class="inline" id="contactForm" method="post" >
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-6 height-contact-element">
           <div class="form-group">
               <input type="text" name="first_name" class="form-control custom-labels" id="name" placeholder="FULL NAME" required data-validation-required-message="Please write your name!"/>
               <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
           </div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-6 height-contact-element">
           <div class="form-group">
               <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control custom-labels" id="email" placeholder="EMAIL" required data-validation-required-message="Please write your email!"/>
               <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
           </div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-12 height-contact-element">
           <div class="form-group">
               <input type="text" name="message" class="form-control custom-labels" id="message" placeholder="WHAT'S ON YOUR MIND" required data-validation-required-message="Please write a message!"/>
           </div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 height-contact-element">
           <div class="form-group">
               <input type="submit" class="btn btn-md btn-custom btn-noborder-radius" value="Send It"/>
           </div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 height-contact-element">
           <div class="form-group">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-md btn-noborder-radius btn-custom" name="reset">RESET
               </button>
           </div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 height-contact-element">
           <div class="form-group">
               <div id="response_holder"></div>
           </div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-12 contact-msg">
       <div id="success"></div>
       </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

JS Script :

```
$('#contactForm').on('submit', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();

            // get values from FORM
            var name = $("#name").val();
            var email = $("#email").val();
            var message = $("#message").val();
            var goodToGo = false;
            var messgaeError = 'Request can not be send';
            var pattern = new RegExp(/^(('[\w-\s]+')|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|('[\w-\s]+')([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i);


             if (name && name.length > 0 && $.trim(name) !='' && message && message.length > 0 && $.trim(message) !='' && email && email.length > 0 && $.trim(email) !='') {
                  if (pattern.test(email)) {
                     goodToGo = true;
                  } else {
                     messgaeError = 'Please check your email address';
                     goodToGo = false; 
                  }
             } else {
               messgaeError = 'You must fill all the form fields to proceed!';
               goodToGo = false;
             }


            if (goodToGo) {
               $.ajax({
                 data: $('#contactForm').serialize(),
                 beforeSend: function() {
                   $('#success').html('<div class="col-md-12 text-center"><img src="images/spinner1.gif" alt="spinner" /></div>');
                 },
                 success:function(response){
                   if (response==1) {
                     $('#success').html('<div class="col-md-12 text-center">Your email was sent successfully</div>');
                     window.location.reload();
                   } else {
                     $('#success').html('<div class="col-md-12 text-center">E-mail was not sent. Please try again!</div>');
                   }
                 },
                 error:function(e){
                   $('#success').html('<div class="col-md-12 text-center">We could not fetch the data from the server. Please try again!</div>');
                 },
                 complete: function(done){
                   console.log('Finished');
                 },
                 type: 'POST',
                 url: 'js/send_email.php', 
               });
               return true;
            } else {
               $('#success').html('<div class="col-md-12 text-center">'+messgaeError+'</div>');
               return false;
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `success()` method you're `reload()`'ing the page.

```
if (response==1) {
    $('#success').html('<div class="col-md-12 text-center">Your email was sent successfully</div>');
    window.location.reload(); // <----- remove this; it's causing the page to reload
}
```

So when your `mail()` function resolves `true`, in your PHP file (`send_email.php`), you're returning `1` to your `AJAX` response which is allowing the `if (response == 1)` to satisfy, and then you're using `window.location.reload()` to reload the page. Removing `window.location.reload();` will keep the page from reloading.

Comment: Ohhh, yes that's true but somehow I'm still unable to send an email...could it be because I have a free plan and the hoster is preventing me from sending emails? or It's more like a code error .Also, thank you for your answer

Comment: That could be from a number of things. But since it's unrelated to this question, please open a new question regarding that issue. But first, I'd recommend you search the site for answers as this very question (Eg. PHP won't send emails) has been asked, and answered, a few dozen times.

Comment: All right  thank you for your advice and  help really appreciated